# Why would ArcGIS Bookmarks in a map not always be available?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, bookmarks

I have a map (*.mxd) and every so often my bookmarks will disappear and reappear, apparently at will.

I am not sure why this is happening.

It seems to be isolated to one particular *.mxd.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Someone at work just pointed the problem out to me, I had the wrong Data Frame was selected.

I don't think it is documented anywhere that Bookmarks are tied to the Data Frame rather than the Map but it makes sense because data frames can be displayed in different coordinate systems with different units and a bookmark is effectively just four numbers and a name.

Comment: Some people may be tempted to close this as too localised in time but I have seen lots of people get caught out by it.  I don't think it is documented anywhere that Bookmarks are tied to the Data Frame rather than the Map but it makes sense because data frames can be displayed in different coordinate systems with different units and a bookmark is effectively just four numbers and a name.